# Characteristic function analytic about 0.

Tags: calculus, probability-theory, analysis, probability-distributions

I have a distribution with the following moments:
$ \mathbb{E}[X^n] = \begin{cases}
0 \hspace{3mm} \text{if $n$ is odd.}\\
C_{n/2}\hspace{3mm} \text{if $n$ is even.}\\
 \end{cases}$
where $ C_n = \dfrac{1}{n+1} {{2n}\choose{n}} $ is the $ n- $th Catalan number. This means that if $ φ $ is the characteristic function of this distribution, then $φ^{(n)}(0) = i^n \mathbb{E}[X^n] $, and so,

$$ φ^{(n)}(0) = \begin{cases} 0 \hspace{30mm} \text{if n is odd.}\\
i^n\dfrac{1}{\frac{n}{2}+1} {{n}\choose{n/2}} \hspace{8mm} \text{if n is even.}
\end{cases}
$$
I want to prove that $ φ $ is analytic about 0.